# How can i display errors in react ; i am getting the array errors from redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

this my redux array that i get from a backend node js api

```html
errors:
errors: Array(1)
0: {location: "body", param: "name", value: "mamadou bah transfert", msg: "ce nom est déja utilisé"}
length: 1
```

And in React Iam triying to show the errors like this

```html
<div class="col m12">
  {this.props.offices.errors.errors?
  <span className="center-align red-text">
   {this.props.offices.errors.errors.map((error,i) => <p key={i}>       {error.param=='name'?error.msg:''}</p>) 
      </span> : '' }
</div>
```

this is   the errors that i get always

[react-errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L91KH.png)

Comment: do `console.log(this.props.offices)` and write output here. Then I can help you as i need to see a structure of your object/list.

Comment: The code in your error doesn't match the code in your question. `this.props.offices.errors ? ` vs `this.props.offices.errors.errors ? `.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `errors` comes from an asynchro request, you should secure the case that the object doesn't exist yet.

`this.props.offices && this.props.offices.errors.errors.map(...)`

However to be 100% sure that it won't fail, I would use a defualt value of `offices` and also check if the `errors` exists and it's an iterable array.

```
const { offices = {} } = this.props;

offices.errors && Array.isArray(offices.errors.errors) && offices.errors.errors.map(...);
```

Comment: that can be the point :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

The point is that when you want to access nested objects, you need to first check whether the nested object really exist and then access it like using below conditional check in your case

```
  <div class="col m12">
        {this.props.offices && this.props.offices.errors && this.props.offices.errors.errors?
           <span className="center-align red-text">
        {this.props.offices.errors.errors.map((error,i) => <p key={"Key-"+i}>       {error.param=='name'?error.msg:''}</p>) 
           </span> : '' }
   </div>
```